# How to create an embedded Excel worksheet in a Word document and populate it with data?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word

Say I have a word document and a Excel worksheet, how can I create an embedded Excel worksheet within the Word document, which you can manipulate just like a normal Excel sheet.

Then, after creating it, how do I populate it with the data from the original Excel worksheet?

Edit: I should have clarified that this should be done programatically in C#.

Comment: What have you tried? I just googled this and found two examples, one for interop and one for the OpenXML SDK.

Comment: I have tried the Standard ways which I found online, but all resulted in the document being faultily embedded (file could not be found at original Location). Thing is I didn't use the base OpenXML, but a solution provided by a third Person, so that could be the Problem. I do have the OpenXML Productivity tool, is the code written in there, just ready to go into a program, or am I missing something?

Comment: Okay, it just clicked! The code generated by the OpenXML Productivity tool seems to be the actual C# code needed to create the opened document. This makes it a lot easier, or at least more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Go to intsert->Object->create new, select Microsoft excel and click ok.

It will insert a blank excel in your word doc.

To edit the excel inserted in word doc, right click, worksheet object-->edit

Then simply copy the values from any other excel and paste it here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have clarified that I Need to do this programatically in C# and not manually as I will be working with multiple hundreds of documents.